# Can't see anything on my on storyboard but the background

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I am new to Swift programming and got some issues after i changed the app's name. When i go to Main.storyboard i couldn't see my buttons but the background and when i tried to run it it looked and worked totally fine.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Are you using an universal storyboard?

Comment: well no the size's iPhone 4.7-inch and it worked fine before i changed the name.